# Strange message when running `python` or `pip` command "dyld[19439]: rebase opcodes terminated early at offset 1 of 9040

Tags: python, macos, pip, neovim

I'm using OSX. When I'm running `python --version` or any other command which starts with the `python` or `pip`, I get this message

```
"dyld[19439]: rebase opcodes terminated early at offset 1 of 9040
```

I didn't find what that could be. I tried a few times to remove Python and install it again, but it didn't work.

Right now, I've added to my .zshrc the following:

```bash
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
alias python3=/usr/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr/bin/pip3
alias pip=/usr/bin/pip3
```

and looks like it works, but I have doubts about whether it's a good solution.

Important to note that provided fix doesn't fully resolve the issue. When I'm trying to run the nvim-dap-python the error log shows the following:

```
[ ERROR ] 2022-10-24T17:53:00Z+0300 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1164 ]    "stderr"    {
  args = { "-m", "debugpy.adapter" },
  command = "/Users/..../api/.venv/bin/python",
  type = "executable"
}   "dyld[20328]: rebase opcodes terminated early at offset 1 of 9040\n"
[ INFO ] 2022-10-24T17:53:00Z+0300 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1128 ] "Closed all handles"
[ INFO ] 2022-10-24T17:53:00Z+0300 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1131 ] "Process closed"    20328   false
```

When I run `which python` without aliases I'm getting this:

```
/Users/<user>/.pyenv/shims/python
```

Comment: Without your aliases in place, what does `which python` say? But note: this community is about programming questions, not about "how do I make tool X on my OS Y work". This is really more for https://superuser.com/ or one of the OS specific communities on the stack exchange network.

Comment: it shows this `/Users/<user>/.pyenv/shims/python`

Comment: I'd recommend moving this question to https://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Or well, I would suggest to research pyenv to understand the tool you are using. Start here for example: https://wilsonmar.github.io/pyenv/ ... point is: in the end, programming requires you to know what you are doing. Be proactive about that ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed all Python versions and all aliases.
After I also removed the pyenv using `brew` command.

After all these steps, I installed pyenv.

Using pyenv, I installed two python versions:

```bash
pyenv install 3.10.4
pyenv install 2.7.15
```

Finally, I set the python versions in the following way:

```bash
pyenv global 3.10.4 2.7.15
```

Seems that everything works now.